# Get products price with tax and discounts in cart/order (Criteo tags)

Tags: cart, price, tax, discount, tags

For the implementation of Criteo tags, I'm trying to get the price (among other things) of all products in the cart (and success page) with tax and discounts. 
I'm currently doing something like this, but it only displays price with discount and without tax :

```
$cartAllItems = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getItems();
foreach ($cartAllItems as $item){
    $price = Mage::helper('tax')->getPrice($item->getProduct(), $item->getProduct()->getFinalPrice());
}
```

I've been testing around a lot of things and can't make it work.
Thx for the help

Answer (score 1):

Check the available parameters for the `getPrice` method:

```
public function getPrice($product, $price, $includingTax = null, $shippingAddress = null, $billingAddress = null,
    $ctc = null, $store = null, $priceIncludesTax = null
)
```

So you need to specify the a third parameter

```
$price = Mage::helper('tax')->getPrice($item->getProduct(), $item->getProduct()->getFinalPrice(), true);
```

If that does not work, you may need to specify the rest of the parameters also based on your quote.